# Take a screen shot of entire Internet explorer document

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I want to take screen shot of entire document of internet explorer document in C#.

I have downloaded so many third party component, but none of them are providing the code for that, can some one please help me out in this?

I am using IE9 and visual studio 10 with framework 3.5.

Comment: c# and internet-explorer tags are not enough to answer.

Comment: do you want a simple screenshot of the visible content of the ie ?

Comment: @Sanket Shah:do you want take screen shot of IE or embed web-browser on your form?

Comment: @dontcare, Not I want to get screen shot entire webpage of Internet explorer. I also went through http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10763/Image-Capture-Whole-Web-Page-using-C, but its giving me blank screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

There's and undocumented Method of the WebBrowser Control called:

`DrawToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds);`

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WebBrowser+Control+DrawToBitmap

Comment: I remember correctly DrawToBitmap is a wrapper around DrawToDC internal method of IE...it's deprecated in ie9+, its still there but some things won't render....I think you will have to look allong the lines that Haden is suggesting but scroll the window and stitch...do able, but animated elements will cause problems

Answer (score 0):

There's a few tutorials on the web that allow you to do this through various methods, this one is a little bit tricky to understand but uses DLL's and calls to them to take a screenshot of the active window.

It also provides some source code and a sample project to help you get started :)

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/11/capturing-the-screen-image-using-c/

Comment: Not I want to get screen shot entire webpage of Internet explorer. I also went through codeproject.com/Articles/10763/…, but its giving me blank screen shots.